# ng2-intl - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, angular2-modules

I realise this is a common issue, but I can't figure out an implementation that works.

I am using Angular 4.2.6 with ng2-intl 2.0.0-rc.3.

I have tried the following and it is still not working:

```
export function intlFactory(http:Http) {
  return new IntlStaticLoader(http, '../../locale', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IntlModule.forRoot({ 
      provide: IntlLoader,
      useFactory: intlFactory,
      deps: [Http]
    })
  ]
});
```

The exception is:

*Function calls are not supported, consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function*

I've taken a look at the source and it does this (any ideas on how I could change it on a fork, so that it works?)

```
export class IntlModule {   
    static forRoot(providedLoader: any = {
      provide: IntlLoader,
      useFactory: i18nLoaderFactory,
      deps: [Http]   }): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: IntlModule,
      providers: [providedLoader, IntlService]
    };   } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you update to the new `ngc` and it's change the optimize then `forRoot` couldn't callback `ngModule` annotation.

I got the one solution to solve similar situation but not guarantee.Despite it's the same way as `angular/route` to outlet `forRoot` and `forChild`.Add this config to your `tsconfig` for your `webpack`.

**tsconfig.yourbuild.ts.**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "declaration": true,
  "stripInternal": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "module": "es2015",
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": [
    "es2015",
    "es2017",
    "dom"
  ],
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "types": [],
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true,
  "baseUrl": "./tmp", //set what you base on.
  "rootDir": "./tmp", //set what you base on.
  "outDir": "dist/"
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotationsAs": "decorators",
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": false,
    "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "router.js",
    "flatModuleId": "@angular/router"
}
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work for me. What specific lines were you thinking would help ?